# Как убрать схлопывание элементов при уменьшении разрешения экрана?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid

На полноэкранной версии меню имеет равные отступы с другми флекс-элементами
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При разрешении менее 1500 px я с помощью грида сделал двухстрочное меню, но далее при уменьшении разрешения элементы схлопываются друг с другом и я не понимаю почему.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 1500px) {
  

   .menu > ul  {
      display:  grid;
      width: 100%;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(4, max-content);
      background-color: red;
  }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так, чтобы при уменьшении разрешения экрана, меню имело равные отступы с другими флекс-элементами?

Весь код https://jsfiddle.net/zobq0nma/
Сам сайт ilini0v1.beget.tech

Comment: grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(170px, max-content));

Comment: это ничего не дало

Comment: gap: 20px; добавить можно в .content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Напишите в ваш медиа запрос `@media screen and (max-width: 1500px)` следующее:

```
.menu {
    margin: 0 10px;
  }
```

Отступы от меню будут по 10 пикселей с обоих сторон

---

Вот так по итогу должно выглядеть:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1500px) {
  .menu > ul  {
    display:  grid;
    width: 100%;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, max-content);
    background-color: red;
  }

  .menu {
    margin: 0 10px;
  }
}
```

Comment: а как сделать так, чтобы расстояние между li  в  меню было не таким большим?

Comment: Столбики в меню при сжатии имеют такие большие расстояния между друг другом потому что эти 4 столбика распределяются по всей ширине блока, то есть по 25% на каждый столбик, при сужении они всё так же имеют свои 25%, но так как сам блок становится меньше, каждый проблемы между столбиками тоже становятся меньше

Comment: **Решения**

1) Самое простое и в принципе нормальное решение это задать фиксированную ширину для меню, в таком случае столбики не будут разъезжаться или съезжаться, и меню всегда будет выглядеть неизменно. Для этого в том же медиа запросе, там где пишите свойства для  `.menu > ul` для свойства `width:` напишите, например, 650px. 

2) написать в `.menu > ul {` в свойстве `width` значение, например, 75%. с процентами можете поиграться сами, как вам больше нравится сделать. В случае с процентами лучше убрать `margin: 0 10px;` у `.menu`